# Graphic card driver not available / supported (matrox)

Tags: graphic-drivers, drivers

I installed Freya (64bit) on a PC I got for free, it's a Dell Optiplex 980 with an i7 @ 2.9Ghz, 4Gb RAM and 320Gb hdd and "sadly" a PCIe Matrox m91xx graphic card (specifically m9120 LP Plus). For a "free" PC not too bad, but its not a fast thing. I bought a 24" Samsung display and want to use it primarly for internet, and couple of excels / words etc (usual home office stuff).

The card works great on Windows with 1920x1080 resolution, but somehow Matrox is not interested into revising their drivers for Linux.

Today I have Freya running with a xorg.conf using VESA and 1280x1024, but I  don't think its using any acceleration. Also, I put modelines for 1920x1080 but I assume VESA cannot handle this resolution (can someone confirm this ? )

Is there a way to get more out of the card w/o the propietary drivers ? Any of you having experience with the provided m91xx Linux drivers and maybe how to install them on Freya ? (I tried and it never worked).

Appreciate your help.

Thks!

Best,
Andres.

Answer (score 1):

M-Series cards have support for Linux, as the vendor specified on the Matrox webpage.

You can download the driver for your card from:

[M-Series driver for Linux 64bits](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/support/drivers/download/http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/support/drivers/download/?id=639)

To install just follow the instructions in NOTES section in that page.

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment. I didnt reply before since I was on work travel. I know about the matrox page and the driver which is there. Sadly, the kernel supported states first in the readme file and is 2.6 to 3.13. As you know, Elementary is on 3.19, and therefore the driver does not work. Also X Server is only supported 6.9.0 to 1.15.

Comment: Have you tried replacing Driver "vesa" with Driver "m9x" in your xorg.conf?

Comment: Yes, I installed the matrox x64 and edited manually the xorg.conf . Get the matrox display and then a black screen. Tried many resolutions and nothing made the driver work. So I changed via console back to vesa and stared this thread to know if someone had the same issue with a similar matrox card. It's sad to see that they don't care abt Linux so much.

Comment: What's the output of xrandr?